# Draw on transparent SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, transparent

I have the following problem: I made a class that extends from SurfaceView, it also implements SurfaceHolder.Callback but when I try to draw a red square, it's always black. Below my code:

First I call the following method in the constructor:

```
 private void initTransparentBackgroundColor(){
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
 }
```

Then, I start drawing:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(10,10,20,20,p);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need another `Paint`? Instead: `canvas.drawRect(10,10,20,20,p)`.

Comment: Unrelated to the original question: are you sure you need a SurfaceView?  If you're drawing on the View, rather than the Surface, you just want to use a custom View.  See http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

To this

```
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Good Luck. :)